# Loading three images in tableView with customCell

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have created a `tableView` with `customCell` which has three images in every row.I have loaded images from folder. When I scroll up or down `tableView` takes time to move up or down. I found some concepts like cache and lazy loading which are loaded images from server. I do not know how to use it in my app.

```
ImagesClass *Obj1 = [imageLists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow];


    UIImage *image1 = [self getImageForImageId:Obj1.imageId FromPath:SAVEDIMAGE_DIR];
    Obj1.thumbImage = [self imageWithImage:image1 convertToSize:CGSizeMake(130, 130)];

    [cell setImage:1 :Obj1.thumbImage RowNo:indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow];


}

if ([imageLists count] > indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow+1) {

    ImagesClass *Obj2 = [imageLists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow+1];
    UIImage *image1 = [self getImageForImageId:Obj2.imageId FromPath:SAVEDIMAGE_DIR];
    Obj2.thumbImage = [self imageWithImage:image1 convertToSize:CGSizeMake(130, 130)];

    [cell setImage:2 :Obj2.thumbImage RowNo:indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow+1];


}

if ([imageLists count] > indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow+2) {


    ImagesClass *Obj3 = [imageLists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow+2];

    UIImage *image1 = [self getImageForImageId:Obj3.imageId FromPath:SAVEDIMAGE_DIR];
    Obj3.thumbImage = [self imageWithImage:image1 convertToSize:CGSizeMake(130, 130)];

    [cell setImage:3 :Obj3.thumbImage RowNo:indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow+2];


}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.delegate = self;
return cell;
```

Comment: Are u loading images from server or locally?

Comment: @VishnuPrasath : "I have loaded images from folder"

Comment: @VishnuPrasath locally.

Comment: Then try by load the images from array outside of UItableViewdelegate.. because each cell will reuse when it jumps out of view so it will take time to set image

Comment: try loading image on imageView in background thread.

Comment: @user2067403 try out my answer and let me know if it works..

Comment: sure.will replay soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes ago I have done this. My experience is, whether you load from folder or net, you have to save the thumbnail copy locally. Then it will be faster to load.

For every image I saved a thumbnail copy in a /thumbnail folder. If for some image there is no thumbnail, I store one then load them. 
By this way, the table cell load the images faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use this [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView). To call this API:

```
ASyncImage *img_EventImag = alloc with frame;
NSURL *url = yourPhotoPath;
[img_EventImage loadImageFromURL:photoPath];
[self.view addSubView:img_EventImage]; // In your case you'll add in your TableViewCell.
```

It's same as using UIImageView. Easy and it does most of the things for you. AsyncImageView includes both a simple category on UIImageView for loading and displaying images asynchronously on iOS so that they do not lock up the UI, and a UIImageView subclass for more advanced features. AsyncImageView works with URLs so it can be used with either local or remote files.

Loaded/downloaded images are cached in memory and are automatically cleaned up in the event of a memory warning. The AsyncImageView operates independently of the UIImage cache, but by default any images located in the root of the application bundle will be stored in the UIImage cache instead, avoiding any duplication of cached images.

The library can also be used to load and cache images independently of a UIImageView as it provides direct access to the underlying loading and caching classes.

Comment: ae u saying just replace UIimageview with ASyncImage?

Comment: @user2067403 Yes. I've done it in my projects and it works wonders.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this simple way

If you loading the images locally then try the following code

under ViewDidLoad do this

```
 Image1Array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initwithobjects:[UIImage imagenamed@"cell1stimage.png"],....nil];
 Image2Array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initwithobjects:[UIImage imagenamed@"cell2ndimage.png"],....nil];
 Image3Array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initwithobjects:[UIImage imagenamed@"cell3rdimage.png"],....nil];

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [Image1Array count];
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];




    UIImageView *imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 42, 42)];
    [imageview setImage:[Image1Array objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageview];
    [imageview release];


    UIImageView *imageview2=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 0, 42, 42)];
    [imageview setImage:[Image2Array objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageview];
    [imageview2 release];


    UIImageView *imageview3=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 120, 42, 42)];
    [imageview3 setImage:[Image3Array objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageview3];
    [imageview3 release];
    }

    return cell;
    }
```

Hope this helps..!

If you found the image still loads slowly then in array add UIImageview instead of UIimage

Comment: I have some confusion how do i change it.I have edited my code.please see it

Comment: @user2067403 in your code u declared that under viewdidload or somewhere in UITableView delegate methods?

Comment: @user2067403 may be u can tryout my code.. becoz in cellforrow method cell is reused every time when its goes out of view..